# Mediawiki throws error when uploading file

Tags: file, upload, mediawiki

On mediawiki version 1.39.2 (in Ubuntu server) I receive an error http 500 when trying to upload a file.

I checked:

- php file_uploads = On: OK
- directory images permissions: OK (www-data owner user and group)
- $wgEnableUploads = true: OK
- disabled all extensions: error still throws
- I examined apache logs but nothing useful

In php error log I found this message repeated a few times:
"PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of Wikimedia\ParamValidator\Util\UploadedFile::getStream() must be compatible with Psr\Http\Message\UploadedFileInterface::getStream(): Psr\Http\Message\StreamInterface in /var/www/html/includes/libs/ParamValidator/Util/UploadedFile.php on line 86, referer: [http://172.48.35.192/index.php/Canoni?veaction=edit"](http://172.48.35.192/index.php/Canoni?veaction=edit%22)

Comment: Try `composer update` in MediaWiki directory.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**: Upgrade to the latest 1.39.x of MediaWiki.  If that isn't an option (it wasn't for me), update your `composer.local.json` so that it requires `psr/http-message` version 1.1 and run `composer update`.

You can do update your composer dependencies with the following two commands:

```
$ COMPOSER=composer.local.json composer require --no-update psr/http-message 1.1
$ composer update
```

**Extended explanation:**

I just ran into this problem with MediaWiki 1.39.3. The error indicates the problem:

```
PHP Fatal error: Declaration of Wikimedia\ParamValidator\Util\UploadedFile::getStream()
must be compatible with Psr\Http\Message\UploadedFileInterface::getStream():
Psr\Http\Message\StreamInterface
```

and there is no way that simply running `composer update` will solve the problem.

Looking at the [implementation of `getStream()` in 1.39.2](https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/g/mediawiki/core/+/1.39.2/includes/libs/ParamValidator/Util/UploadedFile.php#86) (it is the same in master at this point), you'll see that it does not specify a type hint for the returned value.

On my wiki's Special:Version page, I can see that [version 2.0 of psr/http-message](https://packagist.org/packages/psr/http-message#2.0) is installed, but when I compare it with Special:Version on MediaWiki.org (which, as of this writing, is running MediaWiki 1.42.0-wmf.14 compared with my 1.39), I see that it is using [version 1.1 of psr/http-message](https://packagist.org/packages/psr/http-message#1.1).

Sure enough, between version 1.1 of psr/http-message and version 2.0, [return type hints were added](https://github.com/php-fig/http-message/commit/54df5d4d336354de566dc6bb5d99cc0954b117f8) and the [declaration of `getStream()` was changed](https://github.com/php-fig/http-message/commit/54df5d4d336354de566dc6bb5d99cc0954b117f8#diff-5f489453e986e41a5716c36498b8f55ec86e4fccd8c1d1c7a9cca673a1a0a6fa).

Now, why does the newer version of MediaWiki use the older psr/http-message?

After some digging into [git blame](https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/plugins/gitiles/mediawiki/core/+blame/master/composer.json#48) and following the breadcrumbs, we come to [REL1_39 phan failure](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T333987) where phan reported

```
PhanTypeMismatchArgument Argument 1 ($data) is $response->getBody() of type
\Psr\Http\Message\StreamInterface but \MediaWiki\Settings\Source\Format\JsonFormat::decode()
takes string defined at includes/Settings/Source/Format/JsonFormat.php:20
```